# How to push tables through socket

Tags: kdb

Considering the setup of [kdb+ tick](http://www.kx.com/q/d/tick.htm), how do the tables get pushed through the sockets?

In *tick*, it's possible to subscribe with a process (let's say) `a` to the `tickerplant`, which will then proceed to push the data of the subscribed 'tickers' to `a` as new data arrives.

I would like to do the same but I was wondering how. As far as I know, inter-process communication between `q` process is just the ability to transport commands from one process to the other, such that the commands will be executed on the other.

So how is it then possible to transport a complete table between processes?

I know the method which does this in *tick* is [.u.pub](http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/publish-subscribe/) and  [.u.sub](http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/publish-subscribe/), but it's not clear to me how the tables are transported between the processes.

So I have two questions:

- How does `kdb+ tick` do this?
- How can I push a table from one process to the other in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's understand the simple process of doing this:

We have one server 'S' and one client 'C'. When 'C' calls .u.sub function, that function code connects to 'S' using its host and port and call a specific function on 'S' (lets say 'request') with subscription parameters.

On getting this request, 'S request' function makes following entries to its subscribtion table which it maintains for subscription request.

-> Host and port of Client(incoming request)

-> Subscription params (for ex. clients send sym `VOD.L for subscription)

Now when 'S' gets any data update from feed, it goes thorugh it's subscription table and check the entries whose subscription param column value (sym in our case) matches with incoming data. Then it makes connection to each of them using their host and port from table and call their 'upd' function with new data.

Only thing is, client should have 'upd' function defined on their side.

This is a very basic process. KDB+ uses this with  extra optimizations and  features. For ex. more optimized structure for maintaining subscription table,log maintenance, replaying logs, unsubscription ,recovery logic, timer for publishing and lot more.

For more details, you can check definition of functions in 'u' namespace.

Comment: Thank you, that's a very solid explanation. Just one thing that I would like to understand: `''Then it makes connection to each of them using their host and port from table and call their 'upd' function with new data.''`. How does it *send* this new data to the client?

Comment: It can make a handle first time on getting request and store it for future communication. To make handle:  h:hopen`:host:port  .  Check 'hopen' on kx wiki.  To send data using handle:  h (function;func_params). This will call client function. Ex: h (upd;table_name;table_data)

Comment: I understand that (actually I'm already using handles like that), but I was wondering how to SEND the data. Is this done line by line? So sending means I will simply call `insert[table_name;(DATA)]` on the client process? Is that the best way to do this?

Comment: ohh...you can send full data at once using handle and insert it at once on client side.Bulk insert is faster than multiple single line insert.

Comment: That's exactly my question: how does the syntax of such cross-process bulk insert look like?

Comment: Client side it would be simple insert as you mentioned. Question is how Server will send it. If you have rows in tcp buffer limit (which is a case for real time feed)  , server can send that at once like h(upd;`trade;select from trade where sym=`VOD.L) .  If they are going off limit you can break them like   { h(upd;`trade;x) } each 1000 cut select from trade where sym=`VOD.L . 1000 is just for ex., you can tune it according to your application.